# Plotting daytime (without date) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I want to scatterplot a numeric vector versus daytime (%H:%M) in ggplot2.

I understand that

```
as.POSIXct(dat$daytime, format = "%H:%M")
```

is the way to go in terms of formatting my timedata, but the output vector will still include a date (today's date). Consequently, the axis ticks will include the date (March 22nd).

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=as.POSIXct(dat$daytime, format = "%H:%M"), y=y, color=sex)) +
geom_point(shape=15,
position=position_jitter(width=0.5,height=0.5))
```

[image: image of the plot output]

Is there a way to get rid of the date alltogether, especially in the plot axis?
(All info I have found on messageboards seem to refer to older versions of ggplot with now defunct date_format arguments)

Comment: DId you try using `scale_x_continuous(labels = NULL)` ?

Comment: `date_format()` is now in the `scales` package

Comment: I think `scale_x_continuous` does not work on POSIXct vectors, as it produces an error message:  `Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' muss angegeben werden`

Comment: Is `date_format()` even useful here? Looks like `date_format(format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")` also needs a date, so I will probably need another ggplot2 solution. There is this: [link](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html) but it either doesn't address my case, or I don't understand it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide a function to the `labels` parameter of `scale_x_datetime()` or use the `date_label` parameter:

```
# create dummy data as OP hasn't provided a reproducible example
dat <- data.frame(daytime = as.POSIXct(sprintf("%02i:%02i", 1:23, 2 * (1:23)), format = "%H:%M"),
                 y = 1:23)
# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(daytime, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(labels = function(x) format(x, format = "%H:%M"))
```

**EDIT**: Or, even more concise you can use the `date_label` parameter (thanks to [aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461552/aosmith) for the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950909/plotting-daytime-without-date-in-ggplot2/42955819?noredirect=1#comment73016883_42955819)).

```
ggplot(dat, aes(daytime, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_label = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

Comment: Or use the `date_labels` argument as a shortcut, `date_labels = "%H:%M"`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now I wonder if this thread will turn out to be one of those _stackoverflow-"top 1 google search results"_ that I often find when searching for a specific coding issue..

 `# create dummy data as OP hasn't provided a reproducible example`
Okay I get it, will include code for dummy data next time  :)